# Template based - Code generator framework or tool

Tags: java, python, node.js, templates, yeoman

## Summary

Based on the template need to generate a code, Output needs to be a Java/DotNet code

## Analyses

Using the yeoman (https://yeoman.io/generators/). Created a Java -> 
Hello World code generator.

Which takes the string as input and map that in the sysout.

## Code

```
class HelloWorld {
 public static void main(String args[]){
     System.out.println("Hello World");
 }
}
```

Yeoman template code

```
Template folder contains --> <className>Class.java.ejs

Input Args--> <className> , <message>

Input value --> HelloWorld, Welcome

class <%= className%>Class {
 public static void main(String args[]){
     System.out.println(<%= "message"%> );
 }
}
```

Output:
HelloWorldClass.java

Based on the inputs, Values will map in the template and finally. I will get  className.java class.

## Expected

For the template based code generator Found "yeoman" framework uses development language as node.js. Its pretty good.

> Like this any other template based code generator framework available in Python or node or js?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at code generators based on template files.

For example [Telosys](https://www.telosys.org/) which is based on the Velocity template engine.
It is quite simple and easy to use. And above all it can generate any type of language.

See templates examples for Java :
https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java-domain-T300

Answer (score 0):

you can use ANTLR 4 along with StringTemplate or Velocity template to achieve this.
ANTLR would take care of your parsing part and you can use the generated string from ANTLR in your template for substitution.